# Groundwater flow with external forcing

Tags: diffusion, porous-media, transport-phenomena

I want to solve the diffusion equation in porous media with some external forcing at the origin. The regular diffusion equation-

$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}=D\nabla^2h
$$

But I want to solve for pore pressure, so I am using $p=\rho g h$ where h is the pore pressure and h is the hydraulic head and D is a constant. Also, I am simplifying this for 1-D, so this equation becomes -

$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial^2 x}
$$

As initial conditions, p=0 at t=0 $\forall$ x . x$\in${-25,5}.

At the origin (x=0), there is direct injection from a well, and p changes with time according to a function, let's say it is a simple straight line, $p=mt$. How do I solve a problem like this where p is not only changing due to the diffusion but also because of the external forcing? How do I implement this into the diffusion equation? I don't really want the actual solution but rather the approach to solving this problem also if there is anything wrong with my logic. The last time I took an ODE or PDE course was in my first year of undergrad so I am very rusty.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation:

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial^2 x}$$

is a linear PDE and can be separated for the variables $t$ and $x$. I prefer shorthand PDE because you don't have to lug around these cumbersome partials ($\partial$):

$$p_t=Dp_{xx}\tag{1}$$

Assume (*'Ansatz'*) $p(t,x)$ is the product of two functions:

$$p(t,x)=\Theta(t)X(x)$$

Insert into $(1)$:

$$X\Theta'=D\Theta X''$$

Divide by $\Theta X$, to get:

$$\frac{\Theta'}{\Theta}=D\frac{X''}{X}=-m^2\tag{2}$$

where $m^2$ is a positive, Real number. $-m^2$ is the so-called separation constant. $(2)$ can now be split into two **ODE**s:

$$\frac{\Theta'}{D\Theta}=-m^2\tag{3}$$
$$\frac{X''}{X}=-m^2\tag{4}$$

$(3)$ and $(4)$ can often be easily solved, provided you have **suitable boundary conditions** for them. As it stands, so far you only have one initial condition ($p(t,0)=mt$) but no boundary conditions (you need two) for $X(x)$, so you need to think about that.

Comment: But the change of p with time at x=0 is the external forcing that is there on the system. It can't be ignored, it is not a guess, that is how the system is. My problem was not just about solving the equation but about how to implement this into the diffusion equation. I guess my question didn't make it very clear. I'll edit it

Comment: So you have a dynamic boundary condition at $x=0$; *that's hideously complicated*. I suggest taking the question to math.SE. Note that you still lack boundary conditions (you need a total of $3$).

Comment: So could the three boundary conditions be something like p(t,-25)=0 and p(t,5)=0 and the third one is the dynamic boundary condition at x=0?

Comment: Yes but that would still be rather challenging because these $x$ BCs aren't homogeneous. Better would be $p(t,0)=0$ and $p(t,L)=0$ where $L$ is some characteristic length. With such BCs, the ODE for $X(x)$ becomes a simple eigenvalue problem. But $p(0,x)=mt$ remains troublesome. As said: math.SE is your friend.

Comment: If you do post it to math.SE, post a link: my curiosity is piqued! :-)

Comment: Yeah I will post it to math se in a bit, will keep you posted for sure. And as for the conditions I understand the p(t,L)=0, in fact I could have that at +-L which could be two, but p(0,x)=mt is not what I meant. I meant p(t,0)=mt.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that later. But you still need an *initial* condition: $p(0,x)=something$

Comment: To be really clear you need: one initial condition $p(0,x)=f(x)$, two boundary conditions for the $X(x)$ ODE.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't  really remember the notations but if I think about it, all the conditions are $p(0,x)=0$, $p(t,0)=mt$, $p(t,\mp L)=0$. I will read the textbook suggested in the other answer but also post it to Math SE for some more general insight.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4258723/solving-a-pde-with-dynamic-boundary-conditions

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261251/heat-equation-with-time-dependent-boundary-conditions have a gander at that.

Comment: Thanks that helped!

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is usually handled analytically with infinite series (as proposed by Fourier for heat transfer problems). My guess is that you could start solving for the pressure burst problem $p(t,x=0)=\delta(t)$, the corresponding 1D heat problem with "heat burst" at $x=0$ can be found in some textbooks. From there you may find the solution to any forcing function by time convolution of your infinite series solution.

EDIT: equivalent 1D heat transfer problem

For a medium $0<x<a$, initial temperature $0$, an instantaneous source $Q$ (Dirac burst) at $x'$ and boundaries $x=0$ and $x=a$ at zero :
$T(x,t)=\frac{Q}{\rho c}\frac{2}{a}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha n^{2} \pi^{2}t/a^{2}}\sin(n\pi x/a)\sin(n\pi x'/a)$

With $\alpha$ thermal diffusivity, $c$ specific heat, $\rho$ density. I digged the formula in the old book "Conduction of heat in solids" by Carslaw and Jaeger.

Comment: I do plan on handling this analytically in the end if I can figure out the exact problem representation. A simple google search for the heat burst problem didn’t turn up anything, do you know of any textbooks in particular? I will do a more thorough search in a bit, so not a problem if you don’t. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer with the solution to the 1D heat transfer problem

Comment: Thanks! I will go through the book as well. Just from your answer, I guess dirac burst would be the dirac delta?